# How to match all filenames with .csv and .xlsx with a min of one char?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following regular expression `regex_ = r'^((?!~\$).)+\.(xls(x?)|csv)$'` and the code snippet:

```
all_files = [f_path + filename for f_path, _, filenames in os.walk(curr_path) for filename in filenames if re.search(regex_, filename)]
```

where `curr_path` is the current working directory - `curr_path = os.getcwd()`.

Am I right to interpret that the above code retrieves all filenames belonging to files with `.csv` or `.xlsx` extension in the `curr_path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the expression you might be having in mind, could  be:

```
^(?:(?!~\$).)+\.(?:xlsx?|csv)$
```

which would simply fail any such strings:

```
~$.csv
~$.xls
~$.xlsx
```

and it also requires a minimum of one char right before the desired extensions.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/YFdqiI/1)

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YFdqiI/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/YFdqiI/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and suggestions! I'll take a look at the sites that you have recommended :)